# Box shadow not working in mozilla

Tags: html, css

This is working fine with chrome,but box shadow not taking in Mozilla even after adding the browser prefix

```css
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    background: #101010;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 #1b0f0f;
    -ms-box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 #1b0f0f;
    -moz-box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 #1b0f0f;
    box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 #1b0f0f;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.4!important;
    display: inline!important;
    text-align: justify;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<h1>THE <br> SILK <br> ROAD</h1>
```

Comment: it is better to wrap each element in div than using <br> to separate them since you want to style them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `box-decoration-break` and `padding` CSS properties. It would be almost helpful to make this effect in a single sentence break.

```css
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  background: #101010;
  line-height: 1.4 !important;
  display: inline !important;
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  padding: 0 15px 0 10px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h1>THE <br> SILK <br> ROAD</h1>
```

Comment: box-decoration-break is not supported in IE !

Comment: For ie, we can use box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

instead of -

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 pink;
-moz-box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 pink;
box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 pink;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using black color everywhere so you cannot see the effect of the box-shadow. Try this code, it will run in mozilla as well as in the chrome browser.

```css
h1 {
color: #fff;
font-size: 50px;
background: red;
-webkit-box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 pink;
-ms-box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 pink;
-moz-box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 pink;
box-shadow: 15px 0 #0e0303, -15px 0 pink;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1.4!important;
display: inline!important;
text-align: justify;
letter-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<h1>THE <br> SILK <br> ROAD</h1>
```

Comment: Its not working in FF. Its showing shadow only on the last part !

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use box-shadow to have the background color on the text only.
Instead, you can try this:

```css
.background-on-text{
  background-color: #1b0f0f;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 0 15px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="background-on-text">THE <br> SILK <br> ROAD</span></h1>
```

I hope it helps.